# Interpolate between array points

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, interpolation

In the following code I built 2 arrays:

- One contains a "degree data" (so basically an Integer array increasing one by one) representing a portion of degrees in a circumference.
- The second one a "power data" (a Double, whose values keep more or less cubic increasing until a maximum corresponding to a 0 in the first array. Then they will decrease almost as they increased). This array goes for example from values that are more or less -4.0 to more or less -4.0.

I thought I could "simplify" the second one to a parabola (looks very much like one) and use its coefficients (calculated via LinEst) A, B, C and D to **interpolate** data between points.

What I do need is to find with a 0.1 degrees precision the 2 numbers which are nearest to -3.0 and then find their "distance" in degrees.
Problem is: I can't manage to do it. There is something I'm missing and the coefficients seems not to represent my set of data.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim MaxVal As Double, MaxAngle As Integer, CyclicAngle As Double
Dim XValues() As Double, YValues() As Double, Coeff As Variant
Dim LeftAngle As Double, RightAngle As Double, LeftAngleValue As Double, RightAngleValue As Double

' Searches for the maximum value and its angle
MaxVal = -80
ReDim YValues(359 * 3 + 2)
For i = 3 To 362 ' This will fill arrays from a worksheet (defined as Public in
' another subroutine) in which the data starts from row 3. I need the data stored in
' the 2nd column)
    For j = 0 To 2 ' since the array represents a circumference, i make it "cyclic"
        YValues((i - 3) + (360 * j)) = TargetSheet.Cells(i, 2)
    Next j
    If TargetSheet.Cells(i, 2) > MaxVal Then
        MaxVal = TargetSheet.Cells(i, 2)
        MaxAngle = i - 3
    End If
Next

' The following searches the "middle" maximum
i = 0
j = 0
Do Until j = 2
    If YValues(i) = MaxVal Then
        j = j + 1
        CyclicAngle = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
' Searches in the middle for the <-3 (we name it "-4") values
i = CyclicAngle
Do Until YValues(i) < -3
    i = i + 1
Loop
RightAngle = i + 1
i = CyclicAngle
Do Until YValues(i) < -3
    i = i - 1
Loop
LeftAngle = i - 1

' Copying only the "-4" to "-4"
ReDim XValues(RightAngle - LeftAngle)
For i = 0 To RightAngle - LeftAngle
    XValues(i) = YValues(LeftAngle + i)
Next i
' Now correctly store the data in a new ordered array
ReDim YValues(UBound(XValues))
For i = 0 To UBound(XValues)
    YValues(i) = XValues(i)
    XValues(i) = LeftAngle - 360 + i
Next i
```

Here is the critic point:

```
' Gets the coefficients of a 3rd degree curve representing the Y-Array
Coeff = Application.LinEst(Application.Transpose(YValues), Application.Power(Application.Transpose(XValues), Array(1, 2, 3)), True, False)

' Sets the arrays to have a point every 0.1°
LeftAngle = LeftAngle * 10
RightAngle = RightAngle * 10
MaxAngle = MaxAngle * 10
ReDim XValues(RightAngle - LeftAngle)
ReDim YValues(RightAngle - LeftAngle)
For i = LeftAngle To RightAngle
    XValues(i - LeftAngle) = i / 10
    YValues(i - LeftAngle) = Coeff(1) * (i / 10) ^ 3 + Coeff(2) * (i / 10) ^ 2 + Coeff(3) * (i / 10) + Coeff(4)
Next
```

Now if I look at the YValues array, the numbers stored inside don't look absolutely how they should be.
How do I interpolate to find those -3s then?

Comment: Till what row do you continue finding 'expected values' in intermediate variables? because going through the whole code looks somewhat time-consuming without better familiarity with the specific problem

Comment: Well I don't find expected values since most of the code is to let understand how the arrays are populated. At the end I find those 3rd degree LinEst coefficient, but from there on... be dragons

Comment: Your Leftangle, rightangle variables are doubles. Not a good idea to run a loop with doubles and indices and certainly not a good idea to use double to provide array sizes. There will be implicit conversion done, but I'd much rather use `Option Explicit` at the top and use correct data types. Regd. the specific problem, once the types are set correctly (preferably make a new variable as `Long` to loop through and initialize, leaving the angles as double)

Comment: That won't probably be of help: they are Double because I thought I could use them to store an **exact** angle (corresponding to the value of -3 with a 0.1° resolution). The array sizes (if you're talking about the `ReDim`s) are provided because I want to select only a portion of the circumference. For LeftAngle/RightAngle cycling you're perfectly right...

Comment: Yes, so you'll keep them as double and use Long iterators

Comment: did as you suggested, didn't solve the problem but looked cleaner to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in this piece of code: I didn't think I could not "rotate" the XValues array

```
' Now correctly store the data in a new ordered array
ReDim YValues(UBound(XValues))
For i = 0 To UBound(XValues)
    YValues(i) = XValues(i)
    XValues(i) = LeftAngle + i ' Was LeftAngle - 360 + i
Next i
```

I should now be able to find my -3.0 with a simple loop iteration.
There are of course a few obstacles but since I have the LeftAngle and RightAngle references I should be able to solve all.

***Full Solution***

Please see my Question and correct it with the code above. From the "critic point" it goes:

' Gets the coefficients of a 3rd degree curve representing the Y-Array
    ' and build an interpolation array whose points are every 0.1°
    Coeff = Application.LinEst(Application.Transpose(YValues), Application.Power(Application.Transpose(XValues), Array(1, 2, 3)), True, False)
    'TargetSheet.Range("E1:H1") = Coeff

```
' Sets the arrays to be every 0.1°
LeftAngle = LeftAngle * 10
RightAngle = RightAngle * 10
j = CInt(LeftAngle)
k = CInt(RightAngle)
ReDim XValues(k - j)
ReDim YValues(k - j)
For i = j To k
    XValues(i - LeftAngle) = i / 10
    YValues(i - LeftAngle) = Coeff(1) * (i / 10) ^ 3 + Coeff(2) * (i / 10) ^ 2 + Coeff(3) * (i / 10) + Coeff(4)
Next
' Now searches for the -3dB angles with a better resolution
RightAngleValue = 10
LeftAngleValue = 10
CyclicAngle = CyclicAngle * 10
i = 0
Do Until XValues(i) > CyclicAngle / 10
    If Abs(YValues(i) +3) < LeftAngleValue Then
        LeftAngleValue = Abs(YValues(i) + 3)
        LeftAngle = i * 0.1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Do Until i > UBound(XValues)
    If Abs(YValues(i) +3) < RightAngleValue Then
        RightAngleValue = Abs(YValues(i) + 3)
        RightAngle = i * 0.1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
myFunction = RightAngle - LeftAngle
```